# Python doctest with newline characters: inconsistent leading whitespace error

Tags: python, doctest

When writing python doctests, how does one properly introduce newline characters within a string in the test?  Here's a simple example:

```
def remove_newlines(text):
    """
    >>> remove_newlines("line1 \n"
    ...                 "still line 1\r"
    ...                 "now line2 \n"
    ...                 "more line2\n")
    line1 still line1
    now line2 more line2
    """
    return text.replace('\n', '')

import doctest
doctest.run_docstring_examples(remove_newlines, globals())
```

The output of which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: line 3 of the docstring for NoName has inconsistent leading whitespace: '"'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash.

The docstring is itself a string where `\n` means newline. In

```
def foo():
    """
    print "Hello world\n";
    """
    pass
```

the docstring doesn't contain a valid Python statement but contains instead a newline inside the quoted string

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simply replace every `\n` with `\\n`.

Comment: Or instead of replacing `\n` with `\\n`, make the docstring a raw python string: `r"""print "Hello world\n";"""`

Answer (score 28):

The [docstring docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized) actually allude to the problem, but not entirely clearly.

A couple of other stackoverflow threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834916/how-can-i-include-special-characters-tab-newline-in-a-python-doctest-result-s) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862274/doctests-how-to-suppress-ignore-output) were helpful, but not easy to find given my own search criteria.

Here is my actual solution:

```
def remove_CRs(text):
    r"""
    >>> output = remove_CRs("line1 \r"
    ...                     "still line1\n"
    ...                     "now line2 \r"
    ...                     "more line2\r")
    >>> print(output)
    line1 still line1
    now line2 more line2
    """
    return text.replace('\r', '')

import doctest
doctest.run_docstring_examples(remove_CRs, globals())
```

Three things have changed from the original code snippet:

1. The docstring had to be a raw python string.
2. I had to use `print()` on the function output.
3. I had to get over my own confusion with the difference between `\n` and `\r`.  (That one's on me.)

Hope this saves someone else the couple of hours I spent on this.

Comment: btw, I think the name `remove_newlines` is quite misleading if it doesn't remove `\n`.

Comment: Fair enough @flornquake. The issue snuck in because of my bullet #3 above.  Changed the function name to `remove_CRs`. :)

Comment: Suggesting the use of `print` was a great idea - worked well for me thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Just prefixing my docstring with 'r' worked in my case. Python 3.5.1.